# Add card.io in Custom framework face below issue

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, card.io

I want to create a custom framework but also want to add card.io framework into my custom framework. So, anyone have an idea to create this in proper way. If yes then please provide me any idea or demo if possible.**Currently I facing below error at the build time.**

```
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_CardIOPaymentViewController", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in ViewController.o
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_CardIOUtilities", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in ViewController.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

Comment: did you solve it?

Comment: Did you find solution for this? I am also facing similiar errors...